# ArrayList index out of bound but HashSet has no issue

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, hash, collections

I have a simple Graph class, which tracks which elements are linked to eachother using an array of Lists.

I am getting `IndexOutOfBoundsException` when removing an element from the list. My error is given below the code.

But if I change the collection from `ArrayList<Integer>` to `HashSet<Integer>`, it works fine.

Why does `Arraylist<Integer>` type not work here but `HastSet<Integer>` works?

And what is the internal mechanism of removing elements of these collections?

```
class Graph {
    int v;

    ArrayList<Integer>[] connections;

    Graph(int v) {
        this.v = v;
        connections = new ArrayList[v];
        for (int i = 0; i < v; i++) {
            connections[i] = new ArrayList<>();
        }
    }

    void addConnection(int u, int v) {
        connections[u].add(v);
        connections[v].add(u);
    }

    void removeConnection(int u, int v) {
        connections[u].remove(v);
        connections[v].remove(u);
    }
}

class Main{
  
    public List<List<Integer>> criticalConnections(int n, List<List<Integer>> connections) {
        List<List<Integer>> result = new ArrayList<>();
        Graph graph = new Graph(n);
     
        for (List<Integer> connection : connections) {
            graph.addConnection(connection.get(0), 
            connection.get(1));

    for (List<Integer> connection : connections) {
         graph.removeConnection(connection.get(0), 
         connection.get(1));
         graph.addConnection(connection.get(0), 
         connection.get(1));
    }
}
```

---

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 2 out of bounds for length 2
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBounds(Preconditions.java:64)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBoundsCheckIndex(Preconditions.java:70)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.checkIndex(Preconditions.java:248)
    at java.base/java.util.Objects.checkIndex(Objects.java:372)
```

Comment: Please include the full stack trace and highlight the line where the exception occurs. --- "*`connections = new ArrayList[v];`*" - [The usage of raw types is highly discouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it).

Comment: Also, please post a [MRE]. The code you have posted is incomplete.

Comment: I am getting the error on the following line--  graph.removeConnection(connection.get(0),connection.get(1));

Comment: Stack trace-- java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 2 out of bounds for length 2
  at line 64, java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBounds
  at line 70, java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBoundsCheckIndex
  at line 248, java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.checkIndex
  at line 373, java.base/java.util.Objects.checkIndex
  at line 502, java.base/java.util.ArrayList.remove
  at line 105, Graph.removeConnection

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include those information in the question, not in the comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is the method signature:

```
void removeConnection(int u, int v) { // <-- These should be Integer, not int
    connections[u].remove(v);
    connections[v].remove(u);
}
```

The reason is `List` has *two* remove methods:

1. [remove(int index)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#remove(int)) that removes the element at index `index`
2. [remove(Object object)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#remove(java.lang.Object)) that finds and removes `object`

and you are calling version 1, but you want version 2.

`Set` however does not have the `remove(int index)` method, so java *auto-boxes* the `int` to an `Integer` and the  method works as intended (as you discovered).

By changing the method signature to

```
void removeConnection(Integer u, Integer v)
```

the correct version of `remove()` is called. If an `int` is passed to the  method, it will be auto-boxed to an `Integer`, so your usage of this method does not need to change.

---

This is situation is a corner case; it only occurs when the collection type is `Integer` *and* when autoboxing is being attempted. However, it comes up often enough that this special case is worth keeping in the back of your mind, due to the puzzlement and it's hard to pick up even if carefully debugging.